# can't insert special hash code into database

Tags: php, mysql, hash, md5, sha

I wanna save hashed password in mysql database,so I develop following method in CodeIgniter.

```
private function hashing($password = '',$mail = '')
{
    $hashcode = md5($password, $mail);
    return sha1($hashcode,md5($hashcode.$mail));
}
```

for insert:

```
$data = array('mail'=>$mail,'password'=>$password,'actived'=>1,'time'=>time());
$this->db->insert('users', $data);
```

other field inserted correctly instead password.

it will generate something like

```
òLmy­ÉZÔe+ú§3GèÇu‘
```

it can't be saved in mysql database.where is the problem?

**edit** database Collation is utf8_unicode_ci
**edit** I'm using CodeIgniter,so it doesn't need mysql_real_...

Comment: Show us the error you are getting.

Comment: doesn't show any error,warning or notic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant to do this:

```
return sha1($hashcode . md5($hashcode.$mail));
```

Instead of this:

```
return sha1($hashcode,md5($hashcode.$mail));
```

The second argument to `sha1()` is a boolean value, controlling whether it returns the hash in raw or string format (false = string, which is what you want to insert).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the function sha1 correctly, its signature is

```
string sha1 ( string $str [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
```

because the md5 function will evaluate to something that's not false (some string) you'll get raw binary output.

By the way, you're making the same mistake with the md5 function, it has the same signature as sha1

```
string md5 ( string $str [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
```